# How to protect PHPExcel Cell formatting?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to create an "editable area" of the spreadsheet (B3:L99 in the below code), and have protection working just fine all around.  To highlight what may be edited, I've set some colors, borders, etc. and I would like to protect the formatting from being removed when data is being pasted into the cells that they are allowed to edit.

In short, how can I preserver the formatting when data is pasted from a different spreadsheet?

```
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setPassword('PHPExcel');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSort(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatCells(true);
    // this did not work
    // $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatColumns(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setFormatRows(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertColumns(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setDeleteColumns(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setInsertRows(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setDeleteRows(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle("B3:L99")
    ->getProtection()
    ->setLocked(
        PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the password of a worksheet with setPassword():

```
$worksheet->getProtection()->setPassword("the chosen password");
```